# DateTime ParseExact not working with all Strings

Tags: .net, parsing, datetime, powershell-4.0

I'm wirtig a PS script right now where I need to format a string like "20141118133804" to a DateTime using a function:

```
Function Convert-Date ([string]$parseDate)
{        
    [regex]$r = "[^0-9]"
    [string]$parseDate = $r.Replace($parseDate,"")

    $convDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($parseDate,"yyyyMMddhhmmss",$null)

    return $convDate
}
```

The output looks like this:

> Mittwoch, 5. November 2014 09:45:22
>   Mittwoch, 16. Juli 2014 04:51:38
>   Mittwoch, 6. August 2014 05:35:16
>   Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ParseExact" mit 3 Argument(en):  "String was not recognized as a
>   valid DateTime." In
>   C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Get-RDS-CALs-Per-Device.ps1:34 Zeichen:5
>   +     $convDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($parseDate,"yyyyMMddhhmmss",$null)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

I have allready tried to change the CultureInfo but with the same effect, none.

Has anyone of you a idea why this error occurs?

Thanks in Advance.
Greeting and regards
IG

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're trying to parse invalid dates strings, or you have specified the wrong format for your input.

example:

- "20140229133804" is invalid because it references a day that doesn't exist
- "20141811133804" is invalid because it switches the month with the day (regarding your format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"). Notice this case works with days lesser than 12, hence sometimes we get "random" errors.
- "20141118133866" is invalid because because it tries to parse a value of 66 on seconds.
- "20141118133804" is invalid because it will try to fit the value "13" from hours into a 12h valid interval, based on your format "yyyyMMddhhmmss".

If you're loading this list of dates from a file, look out after empty lines on file ending.

Edit:
In this case the problem is on the format string. It should be "yyyyMMddHHmmss" for 24h hour format.

Comment: The values originally look like this "20141118133804.000000-00". 
I do a $val.Split('.')[0] because all values have the 000000-000 after the dot, no exceptions.

These values originate from "Win32_TSIssuedLicense".

Comment: You can quickly find what's the erroneous value by just outputting the input values before the parsing

Comment: Thanks,

but I did that. Sorry i just put the original function up here.
This is what it looks right now:

I compared them the regex is just to make sure there are only numbers in the string no hidden "Tabs" "Newlines" etc.
The values were exported to a file and compared but no noticable differences between the values that work and that don't.

Regards
IG

Comment: Sorry NewLines aren't shown properly so I'll markt them with #\n
`Function Convert-Date ([string]$parseDate)#\n
{#\n
    #\n
    [regex]$r = "[^0-9$]"#\n
    [string]$parseDate = $r.Replace($parseDate,"")#\n
    $parseDate.GetType().FullName#\n
    try#\n
    {#\n
        #$convDate = #\n
        [DateTime]::ParseExact($parseDate.toString(),"yyyyMMddhhmmss", $null)#\n
    }#\n
    catch#\n
    {#\n
        Write-host "Error: $parseDate"#\n
    }#\n
#\n
    #return $convDate#\n
}`

Comment: Can you show me an example of date string that fails?

Comment: Unfortunately the earliest time I'll be able to access the system is on monday, but then I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: Hi,here are some of the values:
20141118133804
20150126154737
20150224154434

Comment: Indeed. And I figured it out the cause. You have an error on your format. Should be "yyyyMMddHHmmss", with capital "HH"

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.

The Format was wrong it should have been "yyyyMMddHHmmss" because ist was in a 24h format.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Microsoft datetime format, known as [`CIM_DATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can get the valid datetime object by using `[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime()` with a supplied string as a whole. Note that if your string has something other than three zeroes in `.000000-000` part, it is time zone offset in minutes, say `"20141118133804.000000+180"`, and needs to be accounted for. The method described takes this into account. Your solution of using `DateTime.ParseExact' with a 24-hour string format is acceptable, but does not take the time zone offset into account. It might be needed when parsing other values of this format.